# MVC C# calling stored procedure with parameters the first parameter is not being recognised

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Can someone please it explain this to me? I have this stored proc:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices] (
      @AreaIdList varchar(max)
,      @FinancialYearStartDate datetime = null
,      @FinancialYearEndDate datetime = null
) as
```

In code I'm trying to call it like this:

```
var areasString = new SqlParameter("AreaIdList", "1,2");
var startDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearStartDate", financialYear.StartDate);
var endDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearEndDate", financialYear.EndDate);

return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>("Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices", areasString, startDate, endDate);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Procedure or function 'Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices' expects parameter
>   '@AreaIdList', which was not supplied.

Say what? I've provided that parameter. Can someone please give me some insight into how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried putting the @ symbol in front of the variable name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call it like so:

```
var areasString = new SqlParameter("AreaIdList", "1,2");             
var startDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearStartDate", financialYear.StartDate);             
var endDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearEndDate", financialYear.EndDate);              
return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>("EXEC Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices @AreaIdList, @FinancialYearStartDate, @FinancialYearEndDate", areasString, startDate, endDate);
```

I believe you could shorten it up a bit too, like:

```
return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>("EXEC Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices {0}, {1}, {2}", "1,2", financialYear.StartDate, financialYear.EndDate);
```

Comment: I could only get the shortened answer to work here. Nothing else seemed to function. Also, when specifying parameters, I had to specify them all, even if there were defaults within the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably expecting the parameter values:

```
return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>("Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices", areasString.Value, startDate.Value, endDate.Value)
```

Comment: What would be the point of creating the parameters though if then you just pass the values. Doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You're right, I just thought you got the syntax mixed up. Are you using the DAAB here?